# Enumerating SysListView32 items with C

Tags: c, sendmessage, syslistview32

All examples I found was C# related, but I'm unfamiliar with it.
My task is to provide some kind of automation for testing. I have installer which first buttons are inside of SysListView32, as I can understand
My target is to select them, choose button by its name and click it
The last part is obvious:

```
GetWindowText(control, window_name, 256);
if(strcmp.....
{
do smth
}
```

But when it comes to SysListView32 I can't understand how to extract its object and names in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at LVM_GETITEM. The MSDN documentation page is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774953(v=vs.85).aspx. The documentation is actually pretty thorough.

A short example that will retrieve the "lParam", the image list index for the icon and the text of an item:

```
LVITEM lvItem;
TCHAR szBuffer[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };

lvItem.mask       = LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
lvItem.iItem      = iItem;
lvItem.iSubItem   = 0;
lvItem.pszText    = szBuffer;
lvItem.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;

if(ListView_GetItem(m_hListView,&lvItem))
{
    /* success! the item details are in lvItem */ 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it. But the problem is ListView_GetItem returns 0. Program logic is the following: I enumerate controls on the window. Using GetClassName I check what is it. if(strcmp(sClassName,"SysListView32")==0){
getLVMitems(control);
} Then I use code you provided.

Comment: ListView_GetItem will return `TRUE` if successful and `FALSE` if it fails. Do you first check how many items are in the listview and use it in a loop, increaming `lvItem.iItem` and what do you set `lvItem.mask` to?